# What happened to Red Skull after Thanos gained the Soul Stone in Avengers: Infinity War?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Red Skull had survived his encounter with the Space Stone in *Captain America: The First Avenger* after all and was transported to Vormir to become Keeper of the Soul Stone.

What happened to him after Thanos took the Soul Stone he was keeping in *Avengers: Infinity War*?

Comment: We don't know yet...

Comment: if comics are any source, he could transferred to '[Soul World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soul_World)'.